# Get how much time (days,hours,minute) remained to assigned Datetime (Android)

Tags: java, android, datetime

I want to get how much date,hours,minutes and second remaining form Date1

```
String RemainingOn = "2013/25/1 22:36:24";
String mDate,mHour,mMinute,mSecond;

public String  DateComparedateTime()
{
 // compare  RemainingOn with now 
   mDate = Difference date with RemainingOn and Now;
   mHour = Difference hour with RemainingOn and Now;
   mMinute = Difference minute with RemainingOn and Now;
   mSecond = Difference second with RemainingOn and Now;

   return mDate+","+mHour+","+mMinute+","+mSecond ;
}
```

Comment: Is there any reason you can't pass in a `Date` or at least a `long` instead of a `String`?

Comment: Yes ,I want to put the return result in textview

Comment: not the return but the argument passed in

Answer (score 2, accepted):

following code gives idea

```
public String getDateDiffString(Date dateOne, Date dateTwo)
{
    long timeOne = dateOne.getTime();
    long timeTwo = dateTwo.getTime();
    long oneDay = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24;
    long delta = (timeTwo - timeOne) / oneDay;

    if (delta > 0) {
        return "dateTwo is " + delta + " days after dateOne";
    }
    else {
        delta *= -1;
        return "dateTwo is " + delta + " days before dateOne";
    }
}
```

if you can use [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/)

Joda Time has a concept of time [Interval](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/key_interval.html):

```
Interval interval = new Interval(oldTime, new Instant());
```